# Docker Toolbox not updating changes even after machine remove

Tags: docker

Using DockerToolbox, I've been trying for the past few days to update my container to run in heroku.
I cant seem to update the code in the container.

Here are some of things I've tried:

- in Docker file change `COPY . /app` to `ADD . /app`
- Removed docker machine and create a virtualbox
- ```
   `docker-machine rm default`
  ```
- ```
   `docker-machine create --drive virtualbox default`
  ```
- build/run docker image
- ```
   `docker build --no-cache -t appname`
  ```
- ```
   `docker run -it -p 8888:8080 appname`
  ```

Also tried `docker build --no-cache .`

Docker File

```
FROM python:3.6

# create and set working directory
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Add current directory code to working directory
ADD . /app/

# set default environment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 
ENV PORT 8080

RUN wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  cd ta-lib/ && \
  ./configure --prefix=/usr && \
  make && \
  make install

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install ta-lib

EXPOSE 8080

CMD gunicorn appname.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Comment: Create a new file called `test.txt` in your code directory, rebuild and run your container and then open a shell in your container by `docker exec -it youcontainer sh`. In the shell list the files - do you see the newly created file?

Comment: @Arik no i do not see the test file

Comment: Did you create the file in the same directory as the Dockerfile?

Comment: @arik yes I did. I actually removed the virtual box couple of  more times and the test file finally showed up. But this doesn’t seem like the proper way to do it.

Comment: Maybe you are running multiple instances of the container and each time you're checking if the file exists after a "rebuild & run ", you are looking at an old container. Did you validate that you have a single instance running?